# Is there a non-relational equivalent of DBI in Perl?

Tags: perl, dbi, non-relational-database

The Perl [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI) module lets me connect to many different types of SQL database transparently. Is there an equivalent Perl module for non-relational key-value pair databases?

For example, an interface that might let me start developing with a BerkeleyDB (or even just a Perl hash?) but switch to something like memcachedb or CouchDB or even a cloud database like those offered by Amazon SinmpleDB or Google AppEngine Datastore.

(Is this what Tie::Hash does? In which case, where can I find a summary of implementations?)

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if [KiokuDB](http://p3rl.org/KiokuDB) is what you want. It has CouchDB, BDB (BerkeleyDB) and DBI backends.

Answer (score 4):

[tie](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html) is a generic mechanism "to hide an object class in a simple variable." [Tie::Hash](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/Hash.html) is a convenient utility class to implement hash ties.

Thus tying objects into a hash is a proper abstraction to access key-value pair databases. To the best of my knowledge there is no common infrastructure to create such ties, so you should create a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) yourself to isolate your project from the various ways to create the different ties.

Answer (score 4):

Generally for every type of key-value pairs storage you will need separate module.

For example:

- Memcache via [`Cache::Memcached`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cache::Memcached)
- CouchDB via [`DB::CouchDB`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DB::CouchDB)
- BerkeleyDB via [`BerkeleyDB`](https://metacpan.org/pod/BerkeleyDB)
- Amazon S3 via [`Amazon::S3`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Amazon::S3)

I'm not sure if there is module for Google AppEngine Datastore - generally, search on [MetaCPAN](https://metacpan.org/) for something that suits you.

Answer (score 3):

[CHI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CHI) looks promising, from the maker of [Cache::Cache](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Cache-Cache).